# How to verify AWS S3 put response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using [aws-skd-s3](https://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk-s3/versions/1.30.1) gem in my Rails project.

Create S3 resoure

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(access_key_id: #####,
        secret_access_key: #####,
        region: 'us-east-1')
```

Create an S3 object

```
path = 'sample'
key = test.csv
obj = s3.bucket(#{bucket_name}).object("#{path}" + key)
```

Store CSV in S3

```
obj.put(body: csv_response, content_type: 'text/csv')
```

How to verify that put method stored the csv in S3 without any issues?

Is there any status code available for put method in S3 to verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to go about it:

1. Store the result. It should be a [PutObjectOutput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Types/PutObjectOutput.html) type object. You can check out the [official](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#put-instance_method) method documentation of the put request method.
2. The second way to go about it is to make a `exists?` call right after your put request is completed. Something like this:

```rb
   s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'ap-southeast-1') # change to the region you use
   obj = s3.bucket('bucket-name').object("path/to/object/in/bucket")
   if obj.exists?
     # Object was uploaded successfully!
   else
     # No it wasn't!
   end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

One way I've seen or read other people doing it is calculating a md5 hash of the original file before upload and then match that with the `etag` value from the response of `obj.put`